# How I can replicate this conection in php?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh

I have this connection in MySQL Workbench and need to replicate it in php, but I don't know how can do it.

```
Connection Method: Estándar TCP/IP over SSH 

SSH Hostname: 11.22.33.44:22
SSH Username: username
SSH Password: 
SSH Key File: ssh-key.ppk

MySQL Hostname: bbdd.server.com
MySQL Server Port: 3306
Username: DBuser
Password: DBpass
```

This is a connection to a AWS RDS/MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
 $db = mysqli_connect('11.22.33.44:22', 'username', 'password', 'DBName', '3306');
```

Comment: Can you please write 'bbdd.server.com' instead of '11.22.33.44:22' and re-try this. And also if you do not have a password( as far as I see you don't have) you can leave ->      ''     (single) for password statement.